# Write a program to output the nth fibonacci number in quinary

Tags: code-golf, quine, fibonacci

Quinary is like binary, except that 1 is represented by the text of the program, and 0 is represented as the backwards text of the program.

The Fibonacci Sequence is the well known sequence

F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)

Write a program that takes some input n and outputs the nth fibonacci number in quinary.

Standard code golf rules apply.

Comment: Can we read program code using filesystem IO?

Comment: @HannesKarppila That's considered a standard loophole for quines.

Comment: Yes it is, but actually question does not use word quine, so I asked. Of course it usually is, but I wanted to be sure if that applies here.

Comment: @Mego I believe you are supposed to output `F(n)` in binary, but with the reversed program for 0 and the program code for 1. So if your code was `1234`, and the input was `4`, you'd output `12341234` (11), and for `5`, you'd output `123443211234` (101).

Comment: @es1024 Ah, thank you for clearing that up, I didn't read so well.

Comment: @Hannes, it's tagged [tag:quine]

Comment: Is the program allowed to be a palindrome? (Same backwards and forwards)

Comment: @Loovjo yes, it is, but I don't think that makes it any easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 30 bytes

```
{s"_~"+UXri{_@+}*;2bWfe|\f%}_~
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e3MiX34iK1VYcml7X0ArfSo7MmJXZmV8XGYlfV9-&input=Mw)

#### How it works

```
{                          }_~  Define a code block, and push and execute a copy.
 s                              Convert the original code block to a string.
  "_~"+                         Append "_~" to the string.
       UXri                     Push 0, 1 and an integer N from STDIN.
           {   }*               Do N times:
            _                     Push a copy of the topmost integer. 
             @                    Rotate the bottom-most integer on top of it.
              +                   Push the sum of the copy and the rotated integer.
                 ;              Discard the topmost stack item, i.e., F(N+1).
                  2b            Convert the remaining stack item to base 2.
                    Wfe|        Logical OR all binary digits with -1.
                                This turns 0's into -1's.
                        \f%     For each binary digits A, take each Ath item of the
                                generated string.
                                This pushes the string itself for A = 1, and the
                                reversed string for A = -1.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 226 bytes

```
s='s=%r;a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,a+b;"*input();print"".join(map(lambda i:(s%%s)*int(i)+(s%%s)[::-1]*(1-int(i)),bin(a)[2:]))';a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,a+b;"*input();print"".join(map(lambda i:(s%s)*int(i)+(s%s)[::-1]*(1-int(i)),bin(a)[2:]))
```

It's quite a heavy modification to the standard Python Quine. It uses `a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,a+b;"` to generate Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I get syntax error on both python 2 and 3.

Comment: @k_g Weird, the program works for me in 2.7.3. Are you sure you copied the whole thing?

Comment: Oh, whoops, it works. I was using python3 in both my tests. Who knew python -> python3?

Answer (score 0):

## , 24 chars / 44 bytes

```
⟮Мȫïⓑⓢⓜ+$?(a=ɕṡ+ᶈ0):aᴙ)⨝
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%E2%9F%AE%D0%9C%C8%AB%C3%AF%E2%93%91%E2%93%A2%E2%93%9C%2B%24%3F%28a%3D%C9%95%E1%B9%A1%2B%E1%B6%880%29%3Aa%E1%B4%99%29%E2%A8%9D)</kbd>

## Explanation

Standard quine framework: `⟮ɕṡ+ᶈ0`

```
⟮Мȫïⓑⓢⓜ+$?(a=ɕṡ+ᶈ0):aᴙ)⨝ // implicit: ï=input
⟮                           // copy block start
 Мȫï                       // get nth Fibonacci number
    ⓑⓢⓜ                  // convert to binary, split along chars, map
         +$?               // is mapitem truthy?
            (a=ɕṡ+ᶈ0)      // if so, replace w/ quine as is
                     :aᴙ)  // else replace w/ reverse quine
                         ⨝ // join
                           // implicit output
```

Comment: What's `ɕṡ+ᶈ0`? Is that a quine builtin?

Comment: Naw, `ɕṡ` refers to character `⟮` and `ᶈ0` is a string representation of the contents of the copy block.

Comment: `ℹ` is the quine function, which isn't used/allowed here.

Comment: That's a good way to quine without a quine builtin.

Comment: Found it by accident.

Comment: Could you add a link to this language?

Comment: https://github.com/molarmanful/ESMin

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 121 bytes

```
$=_=>[...(a=`$=${$};$()`,f=x=>x>1?f(x-1)+f(x-2):x)(prompt()).toString(2)].map(x=>+x?a:[...a].reverse().join``).join``;$()
```

I'm looking for ways to shorten the Fibonacci function...

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 113 bytes

```python
exec(s:="f=lambda x:x<2or f(x-1)+f(x-2)\nfor i in f'{f(int(input())):b}':print(('exec(s:=%r)'%s)[::2*int(i)-1])")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVmj2MpWKc02JzE3KSVRocKqwsYov0ghTaNC11BTG0QZacbkpQGFMhUy8xTS1KvTNDLzSoC4oLREQ1NT0yqpVt2qoAgkpqEOM1C1SFNdtVgz2srKSAusWlPXMFZTSfP/f1MA)